# Linux Kernel CryptoAPI key exchange and key derivation

Tags: symmetric, key-exchange, key-derivation

I have a custom network and I want to implement a symmetric key exchange and key derivation mechanism with ECDH.

I know that I need to use [KPP API and ECDH helper functions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/crypto/api-kpp.html), but I can't find any code examples in Github or elsewhere (kernel documentation is a bit confusing for me, I'm new to this), so I started to think that it's not practical to use ECDH.

If it's not practical, what other algorithms should I research and use?

And if I'm wrong, and using ECDH is practical, where can I find some code examples (it would be great if you provide some links)?

Comment: Does what you want boils down to "a set of C code for performing ECDH and KDF in Linux kernel"?

Comment: @DannyNiu My first question was if it's practical to use ECDH in kernel programming or it's not, because as I said I didn't find any usage example in github.

And if it's practical, I'll be glad if you share with me some examples (if you have some)

Comment: It's definitely practical, the only problem is its over-complicated generalization of key-agreement API. You can of course depend on external dependency for cryptography - in fact, I've made an entirely [free-standing C library](https://github.com/dannyniu/MySuiteA) that can be used in the kernel. Using 3rd party libraries like mine have the advantage of avoiding relying kernel APIs that can change from version to version, but again, a disadvantage would be relying on mine that could also change.

Comment: I think VPN softwares needs to use those KPIs, you can check out OpenVPN, StrongSWAN, and alike.